# yelp displays blank (real) help pages

Tags: yelp

Newish user of Lubuntu 16.10 trying desperately to shed MS Windows. HELP button on more than one utility launches yelp with correct title in title bar, but help window is blank. **HOWEVER**, mouse pointer can find links and hovering displays correct tool-tip. Clicking "link" will go to proper page (title bar changes).

Launching in terminal using

```
yelp help
```

gives many error messages like

```
(yelp:3581): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-lubuntu.css:66:13: The :insensitive pseudo-class is deprecated. Use :disabled instead.
.
.
.
(WebKitWebProcess:3597): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-lubuntu.css:66:13: The :insensitive pseudo-class is deprecated. Use :disabled instead.
.
.
.
I/O error : Attempt to load network entity http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.3/docbookx.dtd.
.
.
.
(yelp:3581): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_accel_label_set_accel_closure: assertion 'gtk_accel_group_from_accel_closure (accel_closure) != NULL' failed
```

but yelp runs as described above. I can't find any place for configuration settings. I would appreciate any and all help with yelp help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why, but yelp works normally now. Many updates have been installed and I have changed preferences on many other things, but nothing specifically related to yelp.